# reactjs Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

I am learning reactjs through a tutorial and ran into this error. That says "Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined" My code is very minimal so I assume that it has to do with the structure of the language. Does anyone know the problem and a possible solution?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
    <title>ReactJs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        var HelloWorld = ReactDOM.createClass({
        render: function() {
        return
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <p>This is some text></p>
        </div>
        }
        });
        ReactDOM.render(
        <HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did your feet this working?

Comment: I inserted your script into my app and still got the same error. It made me realize that as suspected the issue seems to be with the version of Babel that I am using. I'm not sure what the issue is but I will try using another version.

Comment: odd, I just checked this is the one I'm using: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js

Comment: The one that you posted actually worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: i just edited my answer, glad it worked, I bet we see this one pop up a bit more on SO, looking into why, thanks for the good question!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Edit: oddly, after our comments above, I checked to see if it was indeed the babel core version, I am using this one in my fiddle:

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js`

The second I switch to your version above I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined
```

Use `React.createClass` not `ReactDOM.createClass` and wrap multiple lines of html in parenthesis like so:

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/38998/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (     
       <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>This is some text</p>
       </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: any reason why Babel version 6 given that error? I had it too then switch to version 5.8.24 error's gone.

Comment: I just had the same error and found that the version of Babel for the browser we were using was deprecated. The newest version you can use in the browser is https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-standalone

Comment: The version of babel must be less than 6.0.0

Answer (score 11):

Just to be clear, as the other answers are a bit convoluted. The problem was using "babel-core" instead of "babel-standalone". Just look up for a cdn for babel-standalone instead.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js
```

Answer (score 3):

Today is my first day with React, and I've faced this issue when I tried to use Babel to transpile the JSX!

The issue is the version you are trying to use, please use this one instead:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Don't forget to write `type="text/babel"` in the `<script>` tag which you will write the JSX in to let Babel transpile it for you, if you don't, you will find this error *(As I have faced it too! :D)*:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>
```

This is the version of **babel-core** which isn't giving me the error as shown below:

If you want to use the latest version, You can use the **latest standalone version**. (as per 22-Nov-2018)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

But this gives the following warning :

***"You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/"***

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I haven't worked with React before, but there are a few things that I see that may be causing your issues.  First, `React.createClass` instead of `ReactDOM.createClass`.  Second, you need to wrap your html in parentheses:

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>This is some text></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This should get it working