# ReactJs browser Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="ex1.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
```

**JSX code:**

```
// create class
var HelloWord = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Hello Word!</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

// show content
ReactDOM.render(
    <HelloWord></HelloWord>, document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Console message after run:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

Why?

Comment: there is a problem similar with yours you can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672007/reactjs-cannot-read-property-keys-of-undefined)

Comment: Version 6 doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: The version of babel must be less than 6.0.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also ran into the same issue and while surfing the internet I found that there was a problem with the babel-core version that I used. I replaced that with another and got my code to work.

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="ex1.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
```

**JSX**

```
var HelloWord = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Hello Word!</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

// show content
ReactDOM.render(
    <HelloWord></HelloWord>, document.getElementById('content')
);
```

It should work for you too.

**Update:**

You can use `babel-standalone` package for babel compilation with the newer version since `babel-browser` is `deprecated`.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just had the same error and found that the version of Babel for the browser we were using was deprecated. The newest version you can use in the browser is https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-standalone

Comment: Indeed it works with your updated answer. Appreciate the support.