# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined when compiling JSX code with babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to run my first React code but when I refresh the page nothing shows.

This is how my HTML looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>React course</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
    
            <div id="example"></div>
    
            <script type="text/babel">
                ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hi, my name is Sidney</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
            </script>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Anything that I am possibly doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJs browser Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194585/reactjs-browser-cannot-read-property-keys-of-undefined)

Comment: can you provide us the error message?

Comment: @Roman, If you run the Snippet provided by the OP, you will see its cannot read property Keys of undefined which is due to the babel versions. It already contains an answer on the duplicate question

Comment: The version of babel must be less than 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

AS i found on the #[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38196076/4921471), you have a problem with your version of babel. Look at this [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/3vh5dh6j/), uses a previous version of [babel](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js)

```
<div id="example"></div>

        <script type="text/babel">
            ReactDOM.render(<h1 key="0.01">Hi, my name is Sidney</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this version of Babel to transpile your JSX code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```