# React - Minified exception occurred in mvc

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller, babeljs, react-dom

i want add some `react.js` components in `ASP.NET mvc` application. but react.js sometimes working and not working. i am using `gulp-uglify` in gulp.js

i have already try to set  : dev environment

```
set NODE_ENV=development
```

but still I get that error in browser console.
[image: aa]

```
  @* React Library *@
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>

        @* JSX parser library *@
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="/dom.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
```

dom.jsx

```
    var object;
var $item_url = "/item/";
var $c_url = "/category/";
   var TemplateGrid = React.createClass({
  render: function() { 
    return (    
        <div className="product-item column">
          <span className="pin featured">Featured</span>
          <div className="product-preview-actions">
            <figure className="product-preview-image">
              <img src="assets/images/items/flat_m.jpg" alt="product-image" />
            </figure>
            <div className="preview-actions">
              <div className="preview-action">
                <a href={$item_url + this.props.item.name}>
                  <div className="circle tiny primary">
                    <span className="icon-tag" />
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href={$item_url + this.props.item.name}>
                  <p>Go to Item</p>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="preview-action">
                <a href={$item_url + this.props.item.name}>
                  <div className="circle tiny secondary">
                    <span className="icon-heart" />
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href={$item_url + this.props.item.name}>
                  <p>Favourites +</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="product-info">
            <a href={$item_url + this.props.item.ProductId + "/" + (this.props.item.name).replace(/\s/g, "_")}>
              <p className="text-header">{this.props.item.name}</p>
            </a>
            <p className="product-description"></p>
            <a href={$c_url + this.props.item.Category}>
              <p className="category primary">{this.props.item.Category}</p>
            </a>
            <p className="price"><span>$</span>12</p>
          </div>         
        </div>     
    );
  }
});
    var Widgets = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return {
                    items: []
                }
            },
            componentDidMount:function(){               
                $.get(this.props.dataUrl, function (data) {
                    object = data;
                    if(this.isMounted()){
                        this.setState({
                            items: data.tumb                            
                        });
                    }
                }.bind(this));
            },
            componentDidUpdate: function () {
                $(".slide-control.left,.slide-control.right").append('<svg class="svg-arrow"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-arrow"></use></svg>');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('refresh');                   
                }, 1000);              
            },
            render : function(){
                var rows = [];
                var left = [];
                var right = [];
                this.state.items.forEach(function (item) {
                    var i=0;
                    var o = object.objects[i]; i++;
                    document.getElementById('Thumb-title').innerText = o.name;
                    rows.push(<TemplateGrid key={item.ProductId} item={item} />);
                });               
                return (
              <div className="product-showcase">
        <div className="headline primary">
          <h4 id="Thumb-title" />
          <div className="slide-control-wrap">
            <div className="slide-control left">
            </div>
            <div className="slide-control right">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pl-1" className="product-list grid column4-wrap owl-carousel">
            {rows}
        </div>
       </div>                   
 );}
});
ReactDOM.render(
     <Widgets dataUrl="/thumb/8/1" />,
     document.getElementsByClassName('w1')
    );
```

Comment: checkif this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194585/reactjs-browser-cannot-read-property-keys-of-undefined/38196076#38196076

Comment: i have lots of html code in react component. Few lines of code is working but 3 or more lines of code is not working.

Comment: Thats because you have an error somewhere in your code that React is not able to show you because you use the minified version use the non minified versions for everything package to  see the root cause of your problme