# How to use React.js in an html development webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to get this code to work but it just won't display anything onto my google chrome page. It's saved as a .html file on my computer.

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script type='text/jsx'>
        ReactDOM.render(
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>,
            document.getElementById('container')
        );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194585/reactjs-browser-cannot-read-property-keys-of-undefined/38196076#38196076 for creating a standalone app

Comment: A webpage is not going to understand JSX without it being transpiled with babel. You will have to use the `createElement` syntax or use a tool to compile your JSX into native js.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script type='text/babel'>
        ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World!</h1>, document.getElementById('container'));
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```